# how to save data from ms acess front end to ms sql backend?

Tags: ms-access, vba

how to save data from ms acess front end to ms sql backend?

Comment: How do you want to do this? With - VBA & ADO, linked Access tables in SQL Server, linked SQL Server tables in Access, or some combination?

Comment: Perhaps the user lacks fundamental understanding of front-end and back-end split?

Answer (score 1):

It is nearly always better to use linked tables. This makes life much easier because you can update the SQL Server tables and views in more or less the same way that you would update an Access table. Another good way is to use pass-through queries : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968

That being said, here are a few rough notes.

The easiest way to get a useful ODBC string is to link a table using the wizard, you can then look it up using `CurrentDB.TableDefs("NameOfLinkedTable").Connect`

You can use the string like so:

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

strConnect = "ODBC;Description=Test;DRIVER=SQL Server;" _ 
           & "SERVER=ServerAddress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=DBName"

strSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & strConnect & "].[SomeSQLServerTable] (ID, AText) " _
       & "SELECT a.ID, a.Descr FROM SomeAccessTable As a " _
       & "LEFT JOIN [" & strConnect & "].[SomeSQLServerTable] s " _
       & "ON s.ID=a.ID " _
       & "WHERE s.ID Is Null"

db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected
```

You can also update with ADO. There is a great deal of information to be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx
You can get connection strings here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

And some of the odder things you can do:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RecsAffected As Long
Dim scn As String, sSQL As String

''Using SQL Server connection native client
scn = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=ServerAddress;" _
    & "Database=DBName; Trusted_Connection=yes;"

cn.Open scn

sSQL = "INSERT INTO NewSQLServerTable " _
     & "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET " _
     & "('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','C:\docs\ltd.mdb';'Admin';, " _
     & "'SELECT * FROM OldAccessTable')"

cn.Execute sSQL, RecsAffected

Debug.Print RecsAffected
```

Or

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RecsAffected As Long
Dim scn As String, sSQL As String

''Using Jet connection
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

strConnect = "ODBC;Description=Test;DRIVER=SQL Server;" _
           & "SERVER=ServerAddress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=DBName"

sSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & strConnect & "].NewSQLServerTable " _
     & "SELECT * FROM OldAccessTable"

cn.Execute sSQL, RecsAffected


''Using Jet & an external mdb
sSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & strConnect & "].NewSQLServerTable " _
     & "SELECT * FROM OldAccessTable IN " _
     & "'C:\docs\ltd.mdb'"

cn.Execute sSQL, RecsAffected

Debug.Print RecsAffected
```

Comment: To get away from dependence on the DSN, Doug Steele's code is good: http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html

Comment: Hi Remou, is there any problem when using your approach. I think the ms access table will increase its file size when using linked tables depending on the content of each table in ms sql.Remember that Ms Access is capable only UP TO 2 gb. That is why I used VBA and ADO, using a 3-tier approach. I know the development will slower than using linked tables, but from this I am sure that the application will run smoothly in the long run. Any ideas?

Comment: Linked tables have almost no effect on the size of the mdb/accdb and Access has often been used for SQL Server front ends. I have just tried this, and here are some figures: MDB 180KB : 
Linked table=3.4 GB, rows 90533, includes a 'memo' column :
MDB After linking this table 252 kb. I would not recommend scanning all these rows unless you have a fast computer, but there would not be many circumstances when you would require all the records in a recordset, a view of some description will be more friendly.